# Trigger check condition using different table, then change value of row being inserted depending on result

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, db2

Hi I'm currently working on making an SQL trigger that is supposed to say “when inserting a row into the **CUSTOMER_ALIAS** table, check if any of the three address columns in that row contain a value that exists in the **US_STATES** table (which consists of one column – ‘**COUNTRY_NAME**’), if the address of the customer is an American state then set the **INDICIA_STATE** of that row that is being currently inserted to ‘true’

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADDRESS_T BEFORE INSERT ON MYDB.CUSTOMER_ALIAS 
    REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW_ROW
        WHEN
            EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MYDB.US_STATES WHERE US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_1_COUNTRY OR US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_2_COUNTRY OR US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_3_COUNTRY)
        THEN SET NEW_ROW.INDICIA_STATE= 'true'
;
```

I get this error

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CREATE TRIGGER ADDRESS_T BEFORE INSERT ON D;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<space>, DRIVER=4.16.53
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

which according to [IBM's error code list](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_9.0.0/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.dita) seems to be a syntax error, but I dont understand where it's coming from. How is that trigger supposed to look ?

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because the question is about DB2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `then` is part of the trigger syntax.  You can also simplify the logic using `in`.  So this might work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADDRESS_T BEFORE INSERT ON MYDB.CUSTOMER_ALIAS 
    REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW_ROW
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MYDB.US_STATES WHERE US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME IN (NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_1_COUNTRY, NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_2_COUNTRY, NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_3_COUNTRY)
               )
        SET NEW_ROW.INDICIA_STATE = 'true';
```

Comment: that didn't work, it gave me the same error - can anyone confirm if the above is valid syntax, perhaps my issue is caused by something else.

Comment: @borisdzhelali looks like you missed `FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL` or `FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL` clause; [more info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtrigger.dita)

Answer (score 0):

Beside what Gordon said you should state whether it is a row or statement trigger, I also think that the WHEN clause requires it's own set of parentheses:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADDRESS_T 
BEFORE INSERT ON MYDB.CUSTOMER_ALIAS
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW_ROW 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MYDB.US_STATES 
    WHERE US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_1_COUNTRY 
        OR US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_2_COUNTRY 
        OR US_STATES.COUNTRY_NAME = NEW_ROW.ADDRESS_3_COUNTRY
  )
)
    SET NEW_ROW.INDICIA_STATE= 'true'
```

;